# Eclipse stops compiling RenderScript file

Tags: android, eclipse, ant, renderscript

I have a single RenderScript (.rs) file in my Android project: SomeScript.rs

Which has been working fine as I've been developing it. But then I did a workspace clean inside Eclipse, and now it doesn't seem to be recognizing the file as a RenderScript file.

Before, if I had a syntax error, it would notify me about the offending line. But now, no matter what I do to the file, it doesn't get upset. It also doesn't produce the CScript Java wrapper for the script inside /gen. It just errors out with this cryptic message:

```
Error executing Renderscript: Return code 1          line 1 Android AIDL Problem
```

Some brief Googling didn't return much for this error. Anyone seen anything like this before? I'm targeting API level 17. My SDK and ADT plugin are up to date.

Additionally, if I create a brand new .rs file, things work fine. Until I clean... Tried this on two different machines as well. However doing an ANT build of the project works perfectly fine,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem. Our version control software locks every file after you do a check in. The build process within Eclipse requires that the **/res/raw/somescript.bc** file it generates be writable (*even if no changes are being made to the script*).

If it is not writable, it errors out in that very unhelpful way. So if anyone else finds this problem, just don't check the ***.bc** files into your source control!

Comment: The gen, bin source folders, commonly used libraries in libs (support), should also not get checked in the repository, as these files do not have stationary state. Also, if you are working in an environment where same project is shared by several developers (module wise), then you should not share project.properties file (eclipse) as well as the path of the libraries, SDK Path may be different.